# Is there a way to update the version of pitest used in pitclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pitest

I recently installed pitclipse plugin to test my unit tests in eclipse.
Now I face the problem that pitclipse did not get any update since pitest 1.1.9 and I really want to use the latest version (currently 1.4.9).

I have tried several things:
First I was updating the `pom.properties` and `pom.xml` in `eclipse\features\org.pitest.pitclipse.feature_1.1.6.201607050705\META-INF\maven\org.pitest\org.pitest.pitclipse.feature` folder.

This did not change anything.

Next i tried to update the jars `org.pitest.osgi_1.1.9.jar, org.pitest.html-report-osgi_1.1.9.jar, org.pitest.command-line-osgi_1.1.9.jar` in `eclipse/plugins` folder.
To do so I downloaded the latest versions of those jars (except the `osgi` one, since mvnrepositiory does not have this. I replaced with normal `pitest` jar), replaced these files and renamed the new files to match the old file names.

This broke pitclipse, so I removed these changes again.

Did anyone face the same problem and got a work arround? I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pitclipse is actively maintained again so I invite you to [install its latest version](https://github.com/pitest/pitclipse#installation) to benefit from a newer Pitest version. Pitclipse 2.0.0 embeds Pitest 1.4.6, watch [PR #88](https://github.com/pitest/pitclipse/pull/88) to know when Pitest 1.4.10 is supported.

To answer your question, as far I know there is currently now way to manually update the version of Pitest used by Pitclipse.

> ***Disclaimer***: I am the new maintainer of Pitclipse